# When I rotate in Pixi, it rotates from the center

Tags: pixi.js

When I rotate the 'displayObject' with rotation, it rotates from the center on the grid. I want it to rotate from the starting point.

Comment: please add the [easily reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question.

Comment: you can change the `pivot` point of a container: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Container.html#pivot

Comment: unfortunately these were not the solution

Answer (score 0):

By setting the pivot point to the initial position, you can achieve the rotation around the starting point.

```
const displayObject = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.from('your image path'));

displayObject.pivot.set(displayObject.x, displayObject.y);

displayObject.rotation = Math.PI / 4; // Adjust the rotation angle as needed

stage.addChild(displayObject);

renderer.render(stage);
```

Comment: unfortunately these were not the solution